# How to call a method from a class which implements an interface, through the interface?

Tags: java, class, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IStaff {
    public StaffPosition getPosition();

    public String toString();
}
```

and the class:

```
public class Worker implements IStaff {
    private String name = null;
    private String surname = null;
    private int age = 0;
    //StaffPosition is an enumeration class
    private StaffPosition position= null;
    public Worker (String name, String surname, int age, StaffPosition position){
        this.name = name;
        this.surname= surname;
        this.age= age;
        this.position= position;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append(this.name);
        buffer.append(" ");
        buffer.append(this.surname);
        return buffer.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public StaffPosition getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
```

In another class - Building, I have a `HashMap<Office, IStaff> offices`where Office is a normal class which only holds the number of the office and has a getter for that number.

And then in a yet another class Company I have an `ArrayList<Building> buildings`, which holds information about all the buildings of a company. In this class I need to get the age of a worker but how can I do that? So far I have a loop like this to get to the map:

```
for (Building building: buildings) {
    for (Map.Entry<Office, IStaff> office: building.offices.entrySet()) {
        //get the age of a worker
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only real answer is: when you need such an information in places where only your interface should show up, then that information needs to sit on the interface.

So your interface could have a method `getAge()`,  or maybe `getBirthday()`.

Side notes:

- using `I` for "interface" in class names ... is bad practice, or at least: very much against java conventions.
- you don't need to have a `toString()` in your interface. You get one from Object anyway.

(of course, there are dirty tricks, like doing an `instanceof` check somewhere, and then *casting* to the type of the concrete class. But as said: that is really bad practice)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of moving the method in the interface in case I couldn't access it otherwise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make IStaff an abstract class and then call the method.

Comment: I need it as an interface though. Is there a way to get the age through the interface?

Comment: I am not really used to interfaces, much more to abstract classes, but I dont think so. As far as I know, calling methods gets inherited, but not implemented. But if I am wrong, please someone correct me.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks anyway!